# I am new to drupal..I want job application form in careers page

Tags: drupal

I want to know where the below code is placed in drupal files.

```
<div id="application_form">
?php
$block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-29');
print render($block['content']);
?
```

Comment: At career page's template file?

Answer (score 0):

Module invoke Invokes a hook in a particular module
If you want to embed the contents of a block into a node, a custom block, custom module, or a page template, you can use it.

This will help 
https://www.drupal.org/node/26502

Answer (score 0):

You can place this code in template file or put the code in block with PHP filter and put this block on that specific career page content region.

Answer (score -1):

`module_invoke` is a hook for Drupal to get your block content in your `template.php`, `node.tpl.php`, `page.tpl.php`, in blocks and page content using php filter...

```
module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-29');
```

In this example, webform is module name, `client-block-29` is your block id